# Pig Job Failed.Need suggestion

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Please help me to understand why the below join is failing.

**Code:**

```
nyse_div= load '/home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends' using PigStorage(',')as(exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, dividends:double);
nyse_div1= foreach nyse_div generate symbol,SUBSTRING(date,0,4) as year,dividends;
nyse_div2= group nyse_div1 by (symbol,year);
nyse_div3= foreach nyse_div2 generate group,AVG(nyse_div1.dividends);

nyse_price= load '/home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_prices' using PigStorage(',')as(exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, open:double, high:double, low:double, close:double, volume:long, adj:double);
nyse_price1= foreach nyse_price generate symbol,SUBSTRING(date,0,4) as year,open..;
nyse_price2= group nyse_price1 by (symbol,year);
nyse_price3= foreach nyse_price2 generate group,MAX(nyse_price1.high),MIN(nyse_price1.low);
nyse_final= join nyse_div3 by group,nyse_price3 by group;
--store nyse_div3 into 'home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends/output' using PigStorage(',');
--store nyse_price3 into 'home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends/output1' using PigStorage(',');
store nyse_final into '/home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends/output' using PigStorage(',');
```

****Failed Jobs:**

```
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local766969553_0008 nyse_final      HASH_JOIN       Message: Job failed!    /home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends/output,
Input(s):
Successfully read records from: "/home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends"
Successfully read records from: "/home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_prices"
Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "/home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends/output"
Job DAG:
job_local1308827629_0006        ->      job_local766969553_0008,
job_local241929118_0007 ->      job_local766969553_0008,
job_local766969553_0008
2014-11-12 17:00:35,263 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs**
```

Comment: Can you paste the sample input of NYSE_daily_dividends and NYSE_daily_prices files?

Comment: exchange,stock_symbol,date,dividends
NYSE,AIT,2009-11-12,0.15
NYSE,AIT,2009-08-12,0.15
NYSE,AIT,2009-05-13,0.15
NYSE,AIT,2009-02-11,0.15exchange,stock_symbol,date,stock_price_open,stock_price_high,stock_price_low,stock_price_close,stock_volume,stock_price_adj_close
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-08,4.42,4.42,4.21,4.24,205500,4.24
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-05,4.42,4.54,4.22,4.41,194300,4.41
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-04,4.55,4.69,4.39,4.42,233800,4.42

Comment: You should see the stacktrace of the errors in the logs. Paste the stacktrace here to help us understand the failing part.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me. I think you have to paste the complete error log to understand the error.

please see the output that i got for the below input

**NYSE_daily_dividends**

```
NYSE,AIT,2009-11-12,0.15
NYSE,AIT,2009-08-12,0.15
NYSE,AIT,2009-05-13,0.15
NYSE,AIT,2009-02-11,0.15
```

**NYSE_daily_prices**

```
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-08,4.42,4.42,4.21,4.24,205500,4.24
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-05,4.42,4.54,4.22,4.41,194300,4.41
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-04,4.55,4.69,4.39,4.42,233800,4.42
NYSE,AIT,2009-02-11,0.15,4.87,4.55,4.55,234444,4.56
```

**Output from your code**

```
((AIT,2009),0.15,(AIT,2009),4.87,4.55)
```

Comment: I also don't think there is any error as it's very simple code.Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
JobId   Alias   Feature Outputs
job_local1308827629_0006        nyse_div,nyse_div1,nyse_div2,nyse_div3  GROUP_BY,COMBINER
job_local241929118_0007 nyse_price,nyse_price1,nyse_price2,nyse_price3  GROUP_BY,COMBINER

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local766969553_0008 nyse_final      HASH_JOIN       Message: Job failed!    /home/cloudera/NYSE_daily_dividends/output,

Input(s):
Successfully read records from: "

Comment: Can you try to run your pig script in local mode instead of hdfs. This will give some idea.

Comment: Bhai I am running in local mode only.still same issue. Is it because of uge data..Let me try with small data set..